# Gas heating for single flat

Tags: germany, environmental

Assume you own a flat in a larger house with floor heating in Germany and your gas heating breaks down in 2024.

Now a new gas heating is not possible because a new heating requires to be 65% "renewable" by the new law.

If you own the complete house you can either use photovoltaic for that or insulate your house, replace the radiators and use a heat pump.

If you only own one flat, this is more difficult:

- Are there exceptions for that?
- Or is the community of owners obliged to build a photovoltaic, insulate the house, ... ?
- Or is the owner of the flat just out of luck and relies on the goodwill of the community of owners?

Comment: Larger residential houses usually have one boiler in the basement heating all the units. Does this hypothetical case assume that every unit has its own boiler?

Comment: Floor heating can be repaired or replaced.

Comment: @Philipp We assume that every flat has a separate heating. I have actually seen this in many different houses. "Large" might relative, these houses usually have something like 6 to 10 flats.

Comment: @Trish Where do you have this information from? Repairing will be fine, but replacing will require 65% renewable energy.

Comment: Is 2024 a typo? If not, who can say what the legislation would be in 18 month's time? It could be that the 65% "new law" requirement is increased, reduced or even repealed in its entirety. The future is by no means certain.

Comment: @Rick This is not a typo, but a recently passed law coming in effect January 1st 2024, and that is not a "distant future".

Comment: @JFabianMeier it depends on the setup of the floor heating, but usually you could just bolt a different boiler to it (if liquid) or rip out the wire mesh and replace it.

Comment: @Trish Sorry, I cannot follow you. Could you please elaborate how you get 65% renewable energy then? This is required by law from 2024 on.

Comment: A Floor heating can be, depending on the system, be either a normal heating with its heater under your floor (Water system) or you stand on a ginormous resistor that just goes warm because electricity runs through it. You can buy electricity that is certain percentage renewable. A water system you might just swap the boiler from gas to any other water heating solution that is still legal.

Comment: @Trish What water heating solution is still legal? Oil and gas certainly aren't, heat pumps are very inefficient if you have an old house with standard radiators. Using electricity as direct source for heat is extremely expensive.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Wood pellets are another option.

Comment: @Philipp In a single flat?

Comment: If there any joint ownership agreement in place?

Comment: @ohwilleke That's not necessary. If you own an appartment in Germany, there is automatic joint ownership of the house. This is regulated by law in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the new regulation isn't law yet. Currently there is only a concept by the Ministry of Commerce and Climate Protection: https://www.bmwk.de/Redaktion/DE/Downloads/Energie/65-prozent-erneuerbare-energien-beim-einbau-von-neuen-heizungen-ab-2024.pdf

Your case is handled on page 9. When the first heater in the house breaks, the house owners (all appartment owners, *Eigentümergemeinschaft*) would have three years to decide how they intent to replace the old systems and then they would have an additional three years to replace all heating systems in the house with a heater that fulfills the requirement (preferably a central heating system). Meanwhile, you could replace your heater without the 65 % renewables requirement.